# Trying to modify text file with if statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a text file that I am reading in, and based on certain conditions modifying specific lines and rewriting the file to a new text file. My present code mostly works but one of the `elif` statements seems to be simply ignored by Python as there are no run time errors. A MWE is as follows:

```
energy = .1
source = str('source  x y z energy=%f' %energy)
c = energy - 0.001
c_string = str("1010 %f %f" %(c, energy))


f = open("file.txt", "r+")
with open ("newfiletxti", 'w') as n:
    d = f.readlines()
    for line in d:
        if not line.startswith("source"):
            if not line.startswith("xyz"):
                n.write(line)
        elif line.startswith("source"):
            n.write(source + "\n")
        elif line.startswith("xyz"):
            n.write(c_string + "\n")
    n.truncate()
    n.close()
```

The code:

```
elif line.startswith("source"):
    n.write(source + "\n")
```

Works as expected where the line in the text file is replaced with the string titled "source" however the next block:

```
elif line.startswith("xyz"):
    n.write(c_string + "\n")
```

Has no effect. The new text file is simply missing the line that starts with xyz. My guess is my syntax for multiple `elif` statements is incorrect but I am uncertain as to why.

Comment: `if not line.startswith("source")` is triggered when a line starts with `xyz`, so the last `elif` is never executed. Order your conditions from most specific to most general.

Comment: To add to the last comment, why not just end with an else?

Comment: To the first commenter, the line in question is the last `elif`, not the nested one. To the second there might be other lines which need not be affected?

Comment: Also, Bogdan, you don't need to do `n.close()` the with block takes care of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `if` and `elif` handle all the cases -- either the line starts with `source` or it doesn't. I think you need to combine the first `if` and its nested `if` into a single condition:

```
if not line.startswith("source") and not line.startswith("xyz"):
    n.write(line)
```

or the equvivalent (by [de Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)):

```
if not(line.startswith("source") or line.startswith("xyz")):
    n.write(line)
```

Or you can make it clearer by reordering your conditions:

```
if line.startswith("source"):
    n.write(source + "\n")
elif line.startswith("xyz"):
    n.write(c_string + "\n")
else:
    n.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks, this best describes it I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Try your `if` block like this:

```
    if line.startswith("source"):
        n.write(source + "\n")
    elif line.startswith("xyz"):
        n.write(c_string + "\n")
    else:
        n.write(line)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work but the reason why is in the answers below, the script never reaches the last else statement so it doesn't matter if it's else or elif :(

Answer (score 0):

The third elif will never be reached. Here is the code reduced for clarity:

```
if not line.startswith("source"):
# suff
elif line.startswith("xyz"):
# stuff
```

Something that starts with "xyz" does not start with "source".

Comment: If I understand you correctly I need to restructure my initial "if not" statements. something like `if not line.startswith("this" or "this")` `then do this`
`elif this then do this`
`elif this then do this`
as opposed to the nested if statements I have now?